# Installing Ubuntu 32-bit as Virtual Machine(VirtualBox) in Windows 7 - Question

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, windows-7

I have an issue while installing in "Installation Type". Since it is a virtual machine with its own virtual disk, should I choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" or will it have an impact on my actual disk with Win7? https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBXXR.jpg

Secondly, if I choose this option there is a pop-up, what does it mean and am I supposed to accept it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS8NU.jpg

Thank you.

Comment: Use last option "something else" 
When you install system in VM  it means that this virtual computer has it's own hard disk and so on.

Comment: Using that option doesn't let me move further though. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'hard drive' in this case is actually a file on your Windows filesystem, used by the VM. Your Linux installation will not be able to affect anything outside of that file, which it sees as a physical drive. You can go ahead and 'erase everything...'

As for the second message, don't worry about it, for the reasons above. It's just a confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not effect your windows 7 os. Because the hard drive is virtual, you cannot edit the real hard drive it is stored on. So you should erase the vm "hard drive".

Comment: That's what I thought. What about the last message it shows?

Comment: Thats just makimg sure you want to overwrite the vm "hard drive"